# Questions and Tags for PMI/PMP and Concepts

Tags: discussion, questions, tagging

When asking questions related to PMI's PMP framework, how should we tag it? My thoughts are (and the tag I'm using is) "pmi-framework." "pmi" would be questions about the PMI itself (would that be considered off-topic?) and "pmp" could be in reference to the credential.

Comment: Sorry for necro commenting here, but I've just noticed that there are still `PMP` / `PMI` tags available in PMSE... so this topic is needing the `status declined` or tag merge actioned...

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't all these tags generated a lot of confusion?

I mean, a new comer asks a question without much knowledge about tags and would be a pain to moderators and highly reputation members to keep these tags ok.

Shouldn't we let tagging as simple as possible? Just PMI for any PMI-related questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue to just use the tag "PMI".  Questions about PMI itself are probably off-topic.  That eliminates the confusion between PMI and PMI Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the point of the site is to help solving the project management issues. How to solve them, with PMI approach or with PRINCE2 (for example) is a matter of an answer, not a question.

Comment: What about asking questions about PMI and PMP concepts?

Comment: @ashes999 I don't think that this site is suitable for such questions.. The only reason of asking such a narrow question is to get yourself ready for PMP/PgMP certification. There are many other sites/forums for such purpose. We're here to help in project management, not in academic education, aren't we?

Comment: I have a lot of practical questions on how to include certain PMP processes into my normal project management methodology (a type of Scrum). I don't think that's an unsuitable question.

Answer (score 0):

I myself tend to lean towards the most generic tag that will work in a given situation.  I like to use more than 1 (generic) tag, rather than 1 or 2 more specific ones. A question tagged with *pmp* could refer to the credential, the exam, prep books, webinars or really anything.  People coming to this site are going to imbue these tags with meaning & interpretations of their own, often unforeseen by the person who made the tag originally.

I would suggest:

> pmi pmp framework

three separate tags

Keeping in mind that once a person starts entering more than 2 characters for a tag, they will see other tags with the same beginnings, *"pm"* is likely to eventually generate a ton of matches pmi, pmi-pmp, pmp, pmp-exam, pm-tools, pmbok, etc.  Over time, probably way too may tags are going to start with *pm*, making any tag starting with those 2 letter tough to find.

Is the PMP really part of some framework? Is it what most people looking to filter questions related to the PMP would think of?

All this being said, take a look at https://superuser.com/tags, 83 pages of tags.  Could it be improved with cleanup? Yes.  Is it killing the site? No.